# Oracle PL/SQL replicate rows

Tags: plsql

let's say I got a **table `A`** with the following columns:
*`colA, colB, colC`*

I would like to iterate the records on this table and copy them into a new **table `B`** (already present in the database) with these columns:
*`colA, colB, colC, Machine`*
but every record in **table `A`** should be replicated in **table `B`** as many times as the number of rows in the table `MACHINES` (only 1 column: `NAME`)

In my mind I could store the `MACHINES` into a collection of strings and iterate with a loop the records on **table `A`**.
On every iteration I loop in the cached `MACHINES`, write a single row into **table `B`** filling the `MACHINE` field and finally I delete the current row in **table `A`** so that it won't be processed again.

Which is the best way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that simply:

```
with machines as (select 'A' name from dual union all
                  select 'B' name from dual union all
                  select 'C' name from dual),
       tablea as (select 1 col1, 1 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                  select 2 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                  select 3 col1, 3 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                  select 4 col1, 4 col2, 4 col3 from dual union all
                  select 5 col1, 5 col2, 5 col3 from dual)
-- end of mimicking tables tablea and machines
select ta.col1,
       ta.col2,
       ta.col3,
       m.name
from   tablea ta
       cross join machines m;

      COL1       COL2       COL3 NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----
         1          1          1 A   
         2          2          2 A   
         3          3          3 A   
         4          4          4 A   
         5          5          5 A   
         1          1          1 B   
         2          2          2 B   
         3          3          3 B   
         4          4          4 B   
         5          5          5 B   
         1          1          1 C   
         2          2          2 C   
         3          3          3 C   
         4          4          4 C   
         5          5          5 C
```

?

Then you can delete from tableA, something like:

```
delete from tablea ta
where exists (select null
              from   tableb tb
              where  ta.col1 = tb.col1
              and    ta.col2 = tb.col2
              and    ta.col3 = tb.col3);
```

Comment: This is a good answer but not what I'm searching for, because I really need an iterator to avoid a unique transaction. And in the moment I have an iterator I don't want to read every time on machines tables, to make the procedure faster I would prefer to cache them in some way.

Comment: "To avoid a unique transaction" Did you mean to avoid adding duplicate rows (because of a unique constraint)? If so, simply add a where clause to exclude rows already in tableb.

Comment: No, for unique transaction I mean that I want to process 1 record at time. Process it, replicate rows and delete it. Many little transactions. Not a big one as it could be with your code (join).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Performance will degrade much faster the more records you have, due to all the extra, unnecessary context switching.

Comment: Because this table (A) is filled via triggers and I don't want this procedure to  lock it for a long time slowing down my application. I could change my mind too, tests will give me the answer.

Comment: Do you really need the triggers? Perhaps this whole process could be moved into a stored procedure, which handles all the logic in a few SQL statements, rather than looping through things row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow)?

Comment: Yes triggers are really needed. The objective of this procedure is to make these triggers better performing. In the current architecture they write directly on table B bypassing table A. But this is not the best solution maybe cause the execution time depends on number of records on machines table. I prefer to have a faster application (1 insert per trigger) and a procedure that handle the movements from A to B

Comment: Are they row level triggers? Because if so, there's not going to be much you can do to make them faster, as they instantly turn the process into a row-by-row process. Sounds to me like you really ought to take a look at the whole problem, rather than looking at a tiny part of it and trying to polish that up. If you could update your question to include a test case of everything (your tables, your triggers, your input data, your expected output data etc), maybe we could suggest a better solution that avoids triggers altogether.

Comment: Ok so let's say I can accept your aswer. How I can delete only the rows processed in the first query? Because if I delete later I could delete also not processed rows.

Comment: I've included a delete statement in my answer. If you have some means of identifying the rows added to tableb (eg. update time, batch id, etc), then you can restrict on that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve row replication is as Boneist stated, to work directly with SQL sets.

This is not a good way at all to iterate and do it in a loop, like you intend to do. Especially for such a simple problem like yours.

PLSQL must not be used to try imitate what Oracle will in most cases do (far) better as you with loops.